# node readline, node http

Tags: node.js, node.js-client

I'm writing a command line interface which queries a REST server in nodejs.

I read commands from the user using node's `readline.question`. I send via `http.request`, (using [cujojs](https://github.com/cujojs/rest), which however,
I don't think is directly implicated, as I've logged the progress of the call through the library to the underlying `http.request` call).

When a request is sent, it normally is seen by the server. However, occasionally, I can log the call to `http.request` on the client, but don't see it on the server (written in sailsjs).

One odd feature that makes me believe that the readline module is implicated, is that if I type anything such as a space when the request is hung, then the request is often (but not always) sent.

What is going on, and how do I fix it?